# Create Trial Balance by using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hellow Team,
I would like to know how to extract the Trial balance from my journal entry data by using Laravel 9 Eloquent:

My Vouchers Table

```
| id |voucher_date| debit | credit| amount    |
|----|------------|-------|-------|-----------|
| 1  | 2021-09-01 | 8     | 2     | 5000.000  |
| 6  | 2021-09-22 | 22    | 17    | 4750.000  |
| 8  | 2021-09-05 | 8     | 3     | 1485.000  |
| 9  | 2021-08-10 | 8     | 6     | 108.000   |
| 10 | 2021-07-07 | 8     | 23    | 98756.000 |
|11  | Etc.       | ...   |...... |........   |
```

Accounts table

```
| id | name                              | desc                              | status |
|----|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------|--------|
| 1  | Assets                            | Current Assets                    | 1      |
| 2  | Stockholders equity               | Stockholders or Owners equity     | 1      |
| 3  | Liability                         | Liabilities related accounts      | 1      |
| 4  | Operating Revenues                | Operating Revenues                | 1      |
| 5  | Operating Expenses                | Operating Expenses                | 1      |
| 6  | Non-operating revenues and gains  | Non-operating revenues and gains  | 1      |
| 7  | Non-operating expenses and losses | Non-operating expenses and losses | 1      |
| 8  | Etc.                              | More accounts.......              | 1      |
```

My Desired output is like this: (Just an Example)

```
| Date       | Account                          |    Debit |    Credit |
|------------|----------------------------------|---------:|----------:|
| 2021-09-01 | Stockholders equity              |     0.00 |   5000.00 |
| 2021-09-05 | Liability                        |     0.00 |   1485.00 |
| 2021-08-10 | Non-operating revenues and gains |     0.00 |    108.00 |
| 2021-07-07 | Land                             |     0.00 |  98756.00 |
| 2021-02-25 | Land                             | 21564.00 |      0.00 |
| 2018-07-22 | Land                             |  3666.00 |      0.00 |
| 2018-05-14 | Non-operating revenues and gains |     0.00 |    489.00 |
| 2018-09-16 | Equipment                        |   692.00 |      0.00 |
| 2021-04-18 | Non-operating revenues and gains |  4986.00 |      0.00 |
| 2020-04-19 | Land                             |  4956.00 |      0.00 |
| 2019-03-15 | Buildings Asset                  |     0.00 |   4988.00 |
| 2019-12-04 | Inventory                        |     0.00 |   7946.00 |
| 2019-08-25 | Stockholders equity              |     0.00 |  19449.00 |
|            |                                  |          |           |
|            | Balance                          |36,990.00 |36,990.00  |
```

Comment: do you have models?

Comment: Yes; but just common laravel model;

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch >> Don't worry its laravel 8, you need to do the same thing in 9

Comment: to join the 2 tables is there a foreign key?

Comment: @Sumitkumar Yes debit and credit are the foreign keys to the accounts table

Comment: that's kind of confusing share your migrations for both the table.

Comment: Hello after a long search I have found this solution but the problem now the solution only shows a few records and not all records I have in my table: `SELECT vouchers.voucher_date `Date`,
       accounts.acc_name Account,
       CASE WHEN vouchers.debit = $account->acc_code 
            THEN 0.000
            ELSE amount
            END Debit,
       CASE WHEN vouchers.debit = $account->acc_code
            THEN amount
            ELSE 0.000
            END Credit
FROM vouchers
JOIN accounts  ON (accounts.acc_code, $account->acc_code) IN ((debit, credit), (credit, debit));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a new foreign key to the the voucher table. And then you can simply apply the join to get the desired output. AS you mentioned that you are using debit and credit as foreign key how can they be used to uniquely identify the Vouchers table?